# ksh if output gives not found, why?

Tags: shell, if-statement

Why there is `not found` in the output?
I tried to find answer but it's not clear for me and I can't find correct condition to work for me.

```
#!/bin/ksh

a="10.58.0.32"
b=$a
echo "The value of a = $a "

if ["$a"="$b"];
then
echo "if condition met"
fi
```

output is:

```
The value of a = 10.58.0.32
./if-test[7]: [10.58.0.32=10.58.0.32]:  not found
```

Comment: paste your code with appropriate "she-bang" (`#!/bin/ksh`) into https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if [ "$a" = "$b" ];` is the right way to write it. The square opening bracket historically is NO SYNTAX part, but the (once external) NAME of a utility. Nowadays its implemented as shell build-in, but still requiring the same syntax as before, so you need those blanks to separate the "program name" from its parameters. This also results in the closing bracket being no syntax part, but the program called `[` just expects the last param to be a closing square bracket in case the program really was called as `[`.
The (nowadays) build-in util `test` was another link to the same programm, but does not expect the closing bracket as last param, thats all.

Using it without blanks (or tabs), the shell will look for some util called `[10.58.0.32=10.58.0.32]`, which surely does not exist (not found)

Comment: I didn't noticed that spaces between square brackets [ ] and condition. Thanks.